# How can I update a value of an element of an array without changing the position in React native using useState?

Tags: arrays, react-native, use-state

How can I change a specific value of an array using `useState` without modifying it's position. For example: if I wouldn't use `useState`, I can modify the array like this: `checkBox[2] = true`. I tried `setCheckBox[2](true)` but it does work.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

```
const [checkBox, setCheckBox] = useState(
   [true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
);
```

how can I change the value in index 2 of this array to true without changing the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setCheckBox[2](true)` - this will not work because `setCheckBox` is a function, not an array or an object literal. `setCheckBox[2]` is just wrong syntax to use here.

You need to avoid mutating the array directly. Doing this will not trigger a re-render of your component.

To update the state correctly, in your case, you can use `.map()` method to transform the values of the `checkBox` array. `.map()` method will return a new array that will contain the transformed values.

```
// if index is equal to two, return true, otherwise return the value as it is
const updatedArr = checkBox.map((val, idx) => idx === 2 ? true : val);

// pass the new array to state updater function
setCheckbBox(updatedArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply do

```
  const myFunction = () => {
    let arrayCopy = [...checkBox]   // or Array.from() in order to avoid reference
    arrayCopy[2] = true
    setCheckBox(arrayCopy)
  }
```

Like this you skip the loop...